Approximating integral of product of gaussian and cosines
I am trying to evaluate the following integral
\begin{equation}
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{b}\right)\prod_i^N\cos{\left(a_ix\right)}dx,
\end{equation}
where $b>0$ and $a_i$ are integers between 1 and $A$ and $A,N$ are positive integers. I am looking for a way to approximate this integral. So far I have an approximation for small $b$. In this case the exponential dominates and the function is non-zero over a small window around zero. We Taylor expand the cosines to get
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{b}\right)\prod_i^N\left(1-a_i^2x^2\right)dx,
\end{equation}
then if we retain only terms up to $x^2$ we get
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{b}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\left(\sum_ia_i^2\right)\right)dx.
\end{equation}
Evaluating this integral gives us the approximation
\begin{equation}
I\approx\sqrt{\pi b}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}b^{3/2}}{4}\left(\sum_ia_i^2\right).
\end{equation}
Now I am at a loss for approximating this for large $b$. In this case the exponential will very slowly decay and getting rid of the product of cosines isn't as easy.

Sure, I will edit the question.

Would you mind to add pareentheses ?

I believe an exact solution exists, I'm working on it.

A product of cosines can be rewritten as a sum of trigonometric functions. Repeat this until $N=1$ and then you have integrals that can be evaluated in closed form.

I know you can convert the product into a sum, but these sums quickly get out of hand. So I would be interested in a way around these.

There seems to be an exact formula. I am sharing it, both for fun and for you might find it helpful, but it gets pretty difficult to work with as $n$ gets larger, so your request for an approximation still remains reasonable. I will not provide the proof, since it takes a lot of time to write and this question was not about it.
If we set
$$I(\beta,z_1,\dots,z_n)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta x^2}\cos(z_1x)\cdot\dots\cdot\cos(z_nx)dx$$
then we have
$$I= \frac{1}{2^{n}}\sqrt\frac{\pi}{\beta}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\exp\left(-\frac{{\langle v_k,(z_1,\dots,z_n) \rangle}^2 }{4\beta}\right)$$
where the $v_k$ are identified by a choice of $+1$ and $-1$: $v_k=(\pm1,\dots,\pm1)\in \{-1,+1\}^n$, with the convenction that $v_k=-v_k$, so we only count one of the two in the sum.
I know the explanation is complicated, so here are some examples:
\begin{align*}
I(\beta,z_1)=& \frac12\sqrt\frac{\pi}{\beta}\cdot e^{\frac{z_1^2}{4\beta}} \\
I(\beta,z_1,z_2)=& \frac14\sqrt\frac{\pi}{\beta}\cdot\left(e^{\frac{(z_1+z_2)^2}{4\beta}}+e^{\frac{(-z_1+z_2)^2}{4\beta}} \right)\\
I(\beta,z_1,z_2,z_3)=& \frac18\sqrt\frac{\pi}{\beta}\cdot\left(e^{\frac{(z_1+z_2+z_3)^2}{4\beta}}+e^{\frac{(-z_1+z_2+z_3)^2}{4\beta}}+e^{\frac{(z_1-z_2+z_3)^2}{4\beta}}+e^{\frac{(z_1+z_2-z_3)^2}{4\beta}} \right)
\end{align*}
and so on.

This seems indeed to be a closed form formula. But indeed as you noticed the sums quickly get unmanageable. So it would still be interesting to find some approximation without resorting to these sums.

I agree with you, I posted it just for the fun of sharing a closed formula. An approximation is mandatory to calculate $I$ for large $n$.
